# force a string to 2 decimal places

Tags: c#, asp.net, double, repeater

i have a repeater item that displays a double. occasionally the double seems to be coming out with 3 decimal places like this 1165.833. im trying to force it to two decimal places by wrapping it in a string.format method but it still comes out the same:

```
<%# String.Format("{0:f2}",DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pricerange").ToString())%>
```

any ideas why?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`String` simply does not implement `IFormattable`. To use the formatting, remove  .ToString() so that you aren't passing in a String.

```
<%# String.Format("{0:f2}",DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pricerange"))%>
```

To see this more explicitly, run this code:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:f2}", "123.888"));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:f2}", 123.888));
```

which outputs

```
123.888
123.89
```

Comment: Please advice me why in second example that result is **123.89** the string.format ceiling to **123.89** ? I want exactly return **123.88**. in this link example of msdn not correct why!!? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 15):

You can use:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}",value);
```

Comment: you can also use interpolated strings in c# 6+  
$"{myDoubleVar:f2}"

Answer (score 8):

Based on MSDN, you should be able to express the format mask within the call to `DataBinder.Eval`. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d76z3ck%28VS.90%29.aspx

So essentially you should be able to do this - and force only 2 decimal places to show:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pricerange", "{0:##0.00}")%>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try not calling `ToString()` on the output of the `Eval` method - you can't format a string with number formatting strings.

Answer (score 0):

simple: `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pricerange").ToString("C2")`

more @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#CFormatString

Comment: this also adds the currency symbol, which is not part of the requirements