# 2 decimal result in VB

Tags: vb.net

```
    If RadioButtonAC144.Checked = True Then
        TextBoxACScale.Text = TextBoxACReal.Text / 144
    ElseIf RadioButtonAC72.Checked = True Then
        TextBoxACScale.Text = TextBoxACReal.Text / 72
    ElseIf RadioButtonAC48.Checked = True Then
        TextBoxACScale.Text = TextBoxACReal.Text / 48
    ElseIf RadioButtonAC35.Checked = True Then
        TextBoxACScale.Text = TextBoxACReal.Text / 35
    ElseIf RadioButtonAC32.Checked = True Then
        TextBoxACScale.Text = TextBoxACReal.Text / 32
    ElseIf RadioButtonAC24.Checked = True Then
        TextBoxACScale.Text = TextBoxACReal.Text / 24
    End If
```

This is my code, I have several pages(tabs) similar to this, so it's a PITA to change it all up but if it's the only way then so be it, however I just need the result that is showing up in TextBoxACScale.Text to show up to only 2 decimal places.  This code is implemented when clicking a calculate button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168592/force-a-string-to-2-decimal-places

VB.net and C# are the same. using String.Format

Comment: You cannot divide text with integers. You have to convert the text into a number, do the division and then convert back.

Comment: Everything functions now.  I changed the rest of it.  As a heads up the division with the text and such was working fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim Divisor As Integer = 1
If RadioButtonAC144.Checked Then
    Divisor = 144
ElseIf RadioButtonAC72.Checked Then
    Divisor = 72
ElseIf RadioButtonAC48.Checked Then
    Divisor = 48
ElseIf RadioButtonAC35.Checked Then
    Divisor = 35
ElseIf RadioButtonAC32.Checked Then
    Divisor = 32
ElseIf RadioButtonAC24.Checked Then
    Divisor = 24
End If
TextBoxACScale.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(TextBoxACReal.Text) / Divisor).ToString("F2")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If RadioButtonAC144.Checked = True Then
    TextBoxACScale.Text = Round(TextBoxACReal.Text / 144,2)
ElseIf RadioButtonAC72.Checked = True Then
    TextBoxACScale.Text = Round(TextBoxACReal.Text / 72,2)
ElseIf RadioButtonAC48.Checked = True Then
    TextBoxACScale.Text = Round(TextBoxACReal.Text / 48,2)
ElseIf RadioButtonAC35.Checked = True Then
    TextBoxACScale.Text = Round(TextBoxACReal.Text / 35,2)
ElseIf RadioButtonAC32.Checked = True Then
    TextBoxACScale.Text = Round(TextBoxACReal.Text / 32,2)
ElseIf RadioButtonAC24.Checked = True Then
    TextBoxACScale.Text = Round(TextBoxACReal.Text / 24,2)
End If
```