# How to limit datagridview cell value input to 2 numbers after a decimal place?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a number pad with buttons containing text from 0-9 and a button to add a decimal point "." and when you click the button, it adds the text to the datagridview cell.
However, is there any way to limit the input so that you cannot add more than two numbers after the decimal point (as the datagridview column represents the price)?

Something like a rule in the button_click event

```
if (ddr.Contains(".") && ddr.EndsWith(".##"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try something like this

```
        string[] ddrs = ddr.Split('.');
        if(ddr.Contains(".") && ddrs[1].Length == 2)
        {

        }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it enters the if statement when the cell text is for example "88."

Comment: Changed the answer. Have a look

Answer (score 0):

Before assigning the values to gridview cell change the format to this:

```
string valuetobeassigned = ddr.ToString("0.##");
```

**note** : please refer some sources if you want different formatting

[force a string to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168592/force-a-string-to-2-decimal-places)

http://www.daveoncsharp.com/2009/09/formatting-decimals-in-csharp/

[Using String Format to show decimal upto 2 places or simple integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951335/using-string-format-to-show-decimal-upto-2-places-or-simple-integer)